# Azure B2C Format Localized String not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

So I have a user flow in my forgot password process that has a localized string value that I want to load a claim into with their first name. I have followed the documentation [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#formatlocalizedstring)

The problem is the localized string is not changing and instead giving me default values.

This is the page that I'm trying to do it on. It IS a self asserted page.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Select-Method-Email">
  <DisplayName>Allow user to choose their MFA Method</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.radiobutton</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ForgotPasswordOptionsEmail" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I have these values in my localized strings

```xml
<LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.radiobutton.en">
  <LocalizedStrings>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="heading"></LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="FormatLocalizedStringTransformationClaimType" StringId="initial_intro">Welcome Back, {0} </LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Next</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_cancel">Start Over</LocalizedString>
  </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
```

and here is my claims transformation.

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CopyNameToReadOnly" TransformationMethod="FormatLocalizedString">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormatId" DataType="string" Value="initial_intro" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Right now I am at a loss... I thought we could format localized strings on a self asserted page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misunderstanding what `FormatLocalizedString` does and how localisation works on self asserted pages.

`FormatLocalizedString` will set a value in a claim (in your example `readOnlyName`) based on your localised string (`initial_intro`) and an input claim (`givenName`).

I think you're expecting it to update the localisation text `initial_intro` that's displayed on the self asserted page, but it doesn't, it just sets a claim. You're also not actually executing the claims transformation in your self asserted page technical profile.

You could use `FormatLocalizedString` to set a claim, pass that into the self asserted page then use JavaScript on the page to take that claim value and replace the text in whatever HTML element `initial_intro` renders as. You'd end up with something like:

```xml
<LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted.radiobutton.en">
  <LocalizedStrings>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="heading"></LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="FormatLocalizedStringTransformationClaimType" StringId="IntroText">Welcome Back, {0} </LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_continue">Next</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="button_cancel">Start Over</LocalizedString>
  </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>

<!-- other custom policy XML -->

<ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateIntroText" TransformationMethod="FormatLocalizedString">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormatId" DataType="string" Value="IntroText" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="introText" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

<!-- other custom policy XML -->

<TechnicalProfile Id="Select-Method-Email">
  <DisplayName>Allow user to choose their MFA Method</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.radiobutton</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateIntroText" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="introText" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ForgotPasswordOptionsEmail" Required="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Using JavaScript you could then look up the `#introText` element when the page renders, grab its text, hide the element and replace the text in `#initial_intro` (or whatever HTML element that renders as).

Comment: I actually did end up doing something similar. Instead of doing a localized string. i just did a format string on a paragraph type. Did a string transformation and then just displayed that claim in an input claim. Its not EXACTLY what i wanted, but it worked well enough.